# How to hide custom Onsen dialog

Tags: javascript, html, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I have a custom Onsen Dialog with two buttons, and these buttons have onclick code in their html. I create this dialog using a template, and later when I try to hide this dialog with method like this

```
var dialog = document.getElementById("dialogSearchFriend");
dialog.hide();
```

I get an error `"hide() is not a function"`.

I debugged this, and the dialog variable seems to be a template, rather than a dialog.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: tried that, nothing happens

Comment: Ok try as I am answering below.

Comment: This should solve your issues:  http://tutorial.onsen.io/?framework=vanilla&category=Reference&module=dialog

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer From the tutorial mentioned in the previous comments: https://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/YppJpd?&editors=101

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload=function(){

     $("#dialogSearchFriend").fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: nope, still not working, onsen don't work very good with jQuery as much as I know, maybe something to do with that. Also, I'd like the way to close it to be from onsen's api

Comment: no error, like I said, it's most certainly onsen-ui related